# How to calculate Big O Execution Growth Rate?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I just want to know the break down for the Big O execution growth rate for this code, I have try to calculate it but it I got the for loops wrong. so I am completely stuck on this now.

```
     void doInter(int setA[], int setB[], int sizeA, int sizeB)
  {
      const int MAX = 10;
      int sizeR;
    int results [MAX];

   // validate sizeA and sizeB
   if ((sizeA == 0) || (sizeB == 0))
   {
          cout << "one of the sets is empty\n";
   }

   // save elements common to both sets
   for (int i = sizeR = 0; i <  sizeA; i++ )
   {
       if (member(setB, setA[i],sizeB))
       {
          results[sizeR++] = setA[i];
       }
   }

   {
        cout << results[i] << " ";
   }                                                   
   cout << "}" << endl;
  }



  bool member (int set[], int n, int size)
 {
   for (; size > 0; --size)
   {
       if (set[size-1] == n)
       {                                               
          return true;
       }
   }
  return false;                                       
  }
```

Comment: when you ask for `Big O` analysis it it better to post a pseudocode of the algorithm rather than the whole code

Comment: It looks like O(n^2), because member function is called sizeA times, and each time it is called we step sizeB times looking for possible element in setA that is also in setB. I'm talking here about the worst case scenario. So I think O(sizeA * sizeB) should be the answer here. But I don't know how to do more formal analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this code is `O(sizeA * sizeB)`. It is relatively easy to compute - first compute the complexity of the inner function `member` - this is a single cycle and in the worst case it will perform `sizeB` iterations. Now in the outer function you call this function in a cycle of size `sizeA`. Thus the overall complexity is the two complexities multiplied.  The remaining operations are relatively simple with regards to this two cycles.

Also an example where this complexity is achieved is easy to see - use two arrays with no common elements.